# How to plot predicted values with standard errors for lmer model results?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have a transplant experiment for four locations and four substrates (taken from each location). I have determined survival for each population in each location and substrate combination. This experiment was replicated three times.

I have created a lmm as follows:

```
Survival.model <- lmer(Survival ~ Location + Substrate + Location:Substrate + (1|Replicate), data=Transplant.Survival,, REML = TRUE)
```

I would like to use the predict command to extract predictions, for example:

```
Survival.pred <- predict(Survival.model)
```

Then extract standard errors so that I can plot them with the predictions to generate something like the following plot:

[image]

I know how to do this with a standard glm (which is how I created the example plot), but am not sure if I can or should do this with an lmm.

Can I do this or am I as a new user of linear mixed models missing something fundamental?

I did find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154211/how-to-compute-standard-errors-for-predicted-data) on Stack Overflow which was not helpful.

> Based on a comment from RHertel, maybe I should have phrased the
>   question: How do I plot model estimates and confidence intervals for
>   my lmer model results so that I can get a similar plot to the one I
>   have created above?

Sample Data:

```
Transplant.Survival <- structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Steninge", "Molle", 
"Kampinge", "Kaseberga"), class = "factor"), Substrate = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Steninge", 
"Molle", "Kampinge", "Kaseberga"), class = "factor"), Replicate = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), Survival = c(1, 1, 1, 0.633333333333333, 
0.966666666666667, 0.5, 0.3, 0.233333333333333, 0.433333333333333, 
0.966666666666667, 0.866666666666667, 0.5, 0.6, 0.266666666666667, 
0.733333333333333, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.633333333333333, 0.9, 
0.266666666666667, 0.633333333333333, 0.7, 0.633333333333333, 
0.833333333333333, 0.9, 0.6, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.433333333333333, 0.6, 0.9, 0.6, 0.133333333333333, 0.566666666666667, 
0.633333333333333, 0.633333333333333, 0.766666666666667, 0.766666666666667, 
0.0333333333333333, 0.733333333333333, 0.3, 1.03333333333333, 
0.6, 1)), .Names = c("Location", "Substrate", "Replicate", "Survival"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -46L))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `lme4` package but I think that you need to supply test data to `predict()`, and not just the model. The trained model is an important first step, but without input data I don't see how it could be used to predict the outcome.

You could try using

`predict(Survival.model, test_data)`

where `test_data` is the data set for which you want to obtain a prediction.

Comment: RHertel: I am sorry for the stupid question, but for a small study such as this, does it make sense to split the data into a training and test dataset? Would it be more appropriate then to plot my estimates with confidence intervals?

Comment: Read the [r-sig-mixed-models FAQ](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq). It contains an example. Also, there is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14435982/1412059) of mine that points to a thread on the mailing lists that discusses the finer conceptional problems of this.

Comment: @Roland: thank you for the response. I have read through the pages and I understand the approach, but with such a small dataset, it seems splitting it into a training and test dataset seems problematic. I will have to rethink how I what I want to present my model results in a plot or the modelling approach all together!

Comment: I don't see where the FAQ says that you need to split into training and test data to get confidence intervals / standard errors for predictions.

Comment: The issue is that SE's are not standard for MLMs, which is why `lme4` hasn't implemented the functions for them. Do you want the FE standard error only? The RE only? The combined standard error? Also, the structures of your variance matrices matter.

Comment: But you can use `VarCorr(Survival.model)` along with the Z and X model matrices to get the correct terms

Comment: @Roland: I understand that there are not SEs for MLMs, so I gave a simplified example of what I would like to obtain, i.e. a plot with predicted survival with some kind of SE or CI. As I want to visually present my results from my model and this seems an intuitive, if not easy approach, way to present them. I have read the FAQ, and see the example for 'lmer', but what I do not understand being new to these methods, from the example is where the 'newdat' comes from.

Comment: @alex: can you give me an example that I can learn from to use VarCorr(Survival.model) along with the Z and X model matrices to get the correct terms?

Comment: `newdat` is the data you want to predict for. It can be identical to the data you fitted to.

Comment: @KeithLarson There is an example in the [MLM FAQ](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) which was already linked above. Any of the standard texts (Goldstein, Pinheiro and Bates, etc) will also have the details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit: fixed bug in function / figure.*

If you like to plot estimates with CI, you may want to look at the `sjp.lmer` function in the `sjPlot` package. See some example of the various plot types [here](http://strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.lmer/).

Furthermore, the `arm` package provides function for computing standard Errors (`arm::se.fixef` and `arm::se.ranef`)

```
sjp.setTheme("forestgrey") # plot theme
sjp.lmer(Survival.model, type = "fe")
```

would give following plot

[image]

Comment: Just seeing the bug with the x axis labelling for `type = "fe"`, will fix that.

Comment: Ok, package `sjPlot` updated on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/package=sjPlot), also fixing the bug.