# Predicted(?) values from an lmer model

Tags: r, plot, lme4, mixed-models

I have a data frame of bird counts. I have the participants ID number, the number of birds they counted, the year they counted them, their lat and long coordinates, and their effort. I have made this model:

```
model = lmer(count~year+lat+long+effort+(1|participant), data = df)
```

I now want the model to plot predicted values from that same data set. So, that data was for 1997-2017, and I want the model to give me predicted values for each year. I want to plot these, so the final plot will have the predicted count on the y-axis, and the year (categorical) on the x-axis. Each year will have one data point w/ a confidence interval.

I have tried figuring out `predict()`, but I'm not quite sure how to use that to get what I want. It seems to need a new data frame, but I don't have a new data set to run through the model to predict a future count. I want the model to go back and work on the previous data that I put into it already, based off of the Beta values in the output of `summary(model)`.

I found this thread, and it seems to be basically what I'm looking to do, but I can't get the `sjPlot` dependencies to download, `sjlabelled` throws an error every time: [How to plot predicted values with standard errors for lmer model results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196641/how-to-plot-predicted-values-with-standard-errors-for-lmer-model-results?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Standard errors are going to be hard, but take a look at `visreg` for quick predicted effects plot, for example `visreg::visreg(model, "year")`. Mind you that this will set continuous predictors to their median value, and factor variables to the most common one in order to get actual predictions for just `year`.

Comment: @RemkoDuursma Thanks for this. When I do this, though, I'm getting data points plotted into the negative values, though, which doesn't make sense since you can't have negative counts. Any advice?

Comment: Probably because you are plotting contrasts not predictions, try setting `type='conditional'`.

Comment: Interesting, but that's still not changing it unfortunately.

Comment: In that case it is difficult to tell without example data, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the package I was looking for, it's called `predictedmeans` and has a function where you put in the model and the model term you want predictions for `predictmeans(model, model term)`. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [ggeffects-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggeffects), which will be used in the forthcoming **sjPlot**-update to plot predicted values.

```
library(ggeffects)
dat <- ggpredict(model, terms = "dat")
plot(dat)
```

If you're missing dependencies, try:

```
install.packages(
  c("sjlabelled", "sjmisc", "sjstats", "ggeffects", "sjPlot"),
  dependencies = TRUE
)
```

You may even want to install [ggeffects from GitHub](https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects), since the current dev-version has some fixes and improvements for mixed models.

```
devtools::install_github("strengejacke/ggeffects")
```